# What's wrong in my code on problem no 1021(beginner) in URI Online Judge?

Tags: c

I write a code for the URI online judge problem no 1021(Beginner) but it says Wrong answer(100%). I can't understand what's wrong in my code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double input;
    scanf("%lf",&input);

    int note_100= input/100;
    int note_50=(fmod(input,100))/50;
    int note_20=(fmod((fmod(input,100)),50))/20;
    int note_10=(fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20))/10;
    int note_5=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10))/5;
    int note_2=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5))/2;
    int note_1=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5)),2))/1;
    int note50=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5)),2)),1))/0.50;
    int note25=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5)),2)),1)),0.50))/0.25;
    int note10=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5)),2)),1)),0.50)),.25))/0.10;
    int note05=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5)),2)),1)),0.50)),0.25)),0.10))/0.05;
    int note01=(fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod((fmod(input,100)),50)),20)),10)),5)),2)),1)),0.50)),0.25)),0.10)),0.05))/0.01;

    printf("NOTAS:\n");
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n",note_100);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n",note_50);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n",note_20);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n",note_10);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n",note_5);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n",note_2);
    printf("MOEDAS:\n");
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n",note_1);
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n",note50);
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n",note25);
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.10\n",note10);
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.05\n",note05);
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.01\n",note01);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1021

Comment: Whatever the problem is, I am pretty sure it won't require writing *this* kind of code. Please rethink your approach.

Comment: Please read: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 2):

Code is attempting exact integer like math with values like 0.01 that cannot be exactly represented with typical [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). This often leads to unexpected results.

Change to integers of smallest unit.  (Scale by 100)

Avoid repeated calculations by reducing `cent` at each step rather than recalculate from the beginning.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double input;
    scanf("%lf",&input);
    long long cent = llround(input * 100);  // scale by 100 and round

    long long note_100 = cent/10000;  // divide by scaled amount (100*100)
    cent %= 10000;
    int note_50 = cent/5000;
    cent %= 5000;
    int note_20 = cent/2000;
    cent %= 2000;
    ...
    printf("NOTAS:\n");
    printf("%lld nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", note_100);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", note_50);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", note_20);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```